# Is there anywhere that I can obtain global UV data in either raster or vector format?

Tags: raster, data, vector

I'm looking for some UV data (currently with no spatial or temporal resolutions in mind, but ideally split into UV-A and UV-B) for the whole earth. Can anyone recommend a source for data like this or point me in the right direction?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**World Ozone and Ultraviolet Radiation Data Centre (WOUDC)**

http://www.woudc.org/data_e.html

The UV data archive contains the following data categories:

```
Broad-band
Multi-band
Spectral
```

**Spectral UV**

FTP
ftp://ftp.tor.ec.gc.ca/Summaries/Spectral_UV/

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm trying to access the ftp site but get permission denied...where can I sign up for an account or are there guest credentials that I can use?

Comment: go through http://www.woudc.org/data_e.html and just accept the agreement then you have access.

Answer (score 1):

**(Disclosure: I am part of the WOUDC data centre renewal team)**

The data centre is undergoing [renewal](http://beta.woudc.org) in order to modernize client services. Improved data access is one of the major enhancements (which includes geospatial web services and formats; see the [data access about page](http://beta.woudc.org/about/data-access.php) for details).

Users are encouraged to provide [feedback](http://beta.woudc.org/contact.php#email) against the beta.  For specific issues, please provide the URL and information / steps to identify / reproduce the issue.

Comment: FYI as a following I'm happy to announce we are now live at http://woudc.org.  Feedback welcome!